# Does Java guarantee the persistence of the reference to the outer class? How is the following trace possible?

Tags: java, reference, inner-classes

**Question**

When an inner class (N.B.: non static) is instantiated, it will get a reference to the outer class (upon its construction). Which guarantees apply in this case (if any) regarding the persistence of this reference?

**Long explanation (trying to give a sense to the question)**

Consider this simple code:

```
public class OuterInnerExample {

    private int mInt;

    public void startJob() {
        InnerRunnable r = new InnerRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }

    private class InnerRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            int localInt = mInt;
            System.out.println(localInt);
        }
    }
}
```

After compilation, if we decompile the class files (I used `jad`), we can observe that `InnerRunnable` has a `this$0` member which is the reference to `OuterInnerExample` object.

This reference is set in the compiler-synthesized constructor of `InnerRunnable`, before calling `super()` (so this avoids the situation in which `this$0` may be `null` when the object is used before its construction is completed, i.e., through the base class).

When `InnerRunnable` wants to access `mInt`, it will use a static getter synthesized by the compiler, that takes a reference to `OuterInnerExample` as a parameter (this is going to be `this$0`). This getter is the `access$100` method.

For reference, the decompiled Java can be found here: http://pastebin.com/gr8GB03t.

Now, the whole problem is that I have observed (and cannot explain), a stack trace similar to the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at <package.name>.OuterInnerExample.access$100(<line where "class OuterInnerExample" is>
    at <package.name>.OuterInnerExample$InnerRunnable.run(<line where "public void run()" is>)
```

which makes me think that `this$0` must have been `null` at that point.

Comment: Is `OuterInnerExample` an nested class itself?

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: Good, thorough question! Anyway I could be out of my league and speaking from a silly place due to the paste being decompiled code, but what's with the `super()` placement?

Comment: @BobbyDigital If super was called **before** setting `this$0`, then if the base class called a method that late-binded to an implementation defined in the `InnerRunnable` class that used a member of the outer class, then `this$0` was certainly `null` and its usage in any of the `static$x00` methods would have certainly led to a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: as the [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) states:

> When an inner class (whose declaration does not occur in a static
>   context) refers to an instance variable that is a member of a
>   lexically enclosing class, the variable of the corresponding lexically
>   enclosing instance is used.

Read [JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) about the happens-before relations:

> The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other than default-writes) of a program.

Default initialization here means the assignment of default values to fields.

Since the field `private int mInt` is primitive it can't be `null` so you must look elsewhere.

My guess is that you are using some custom compiler since this part:

```
private OuterInnerExample$InnerRunnable(OuterInnerExample outerinnerexample)
{
    this$0 = outerinnerexample;
    super();
}
```

leads to a compile-time error. You have to call `super()` in the first line of a constructor.

I actually copy-pasted your original code and used java 1.7 to execute it and it worked without problems so we are missing context here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem is that, that is already compiled code and you should not try to compile it again. It is decompiled from the *.class files. That is just to see what is the real code that is executed by the VM. The NPE comes from the implementation of the static$100 method, which accesses a reference provided as an argument.